# Plot boolean values on a time based line graph

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting a time based line graph and would like to add a boolean data series to it.

Is it possible to have the boolean data highlight the full height of the canvas of the graph where the value is true?

Plotfile:

```
set datafile separator ","
set terminal pngcairo size 800,400
set title "Solar charge monitor"
set yrange [0:]
set ylabel "V"
set y2range [0:]
set y2label "A"
set y2tics
set xlabel "Date"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
set key left top
set grid
set output "samplePlot.png"
plot "sampleData.csv" using 1:2 with lines lw 2 title 'Batt (V)', \
     "sampleData.csv" using 1:3 with lines lw 2 title 'Solar (V)', \
     "sampleData.csv" using 1:4 with lines lw 2 title 'Charge (A)' axes x1y2, \
     "sampleData.csv" using 1:5 with lines lw 2 title 'Load (A)' axes x1y2
```

Sample Data:

```
time,V_Batt,V_SolarV,A_Charge,A_Load,bool_charging
2014-09-25T07:06:03.358Z,13.20,14.38,0.52,0.03,1
2014-09-25T07:05:03.639Z,13.16,14.14,0.52,0.05,1
2014-09-25T07:04:02.856Z,13.18,14.19,0.54,0.03,1
2014-09-25T07:03:03.141Z,13.18,14.24,0.52,0.03,1
2014-09-25T07:02:03.410Z,13.18,14.09,0.52,0.03,1
2014-09-25T07:01:03.604Z,13.20,14.38,0.54,0.03,1
2014-09-25T07:00:02.766Z,13.11,14.28,0.50,0.02,1
2014-09-25T06:59:03.025Z,13.09,14.28,0.48,0.02,1
2014-09-25T06:58:03.302Z,13.11,14.28,0.43,0.02,1
2014-09-25T06:57:03.445Z,13.18,14.28,0.56,0.05,1
2014-09-25T06:56:02.611Z,13.16,14.14,0.52,0.03,1
2014-09-25T06:55:02.901Z,13.09,14.58,0.48,0.01,1
2014-09-25T06:54:03.178Z,13.09,14.48,0.52,0.02,1
2014-09-25T06:53:03.432Z,13.13,14.53,0.54,0.06,1
2014-09-25T06:52:03.630Z,13.11,14.28,0.48,0.03,1
2014-09-25T06:51:02.763Z,13.16,14.14,0.54,0.05,1
2014-09-25T06:50:03.068Z,13.16,14.28,0.54,0.03,1
2014-09-25T06:49:03.388Z,13.07,14.38,0.50,0.03,1
2014-09-25T06:48:02.683Z,13.09,14.33,0.50,0.03,1
2014-09-25T06:47:02.967Z,13.07,14.04,0.48,0.02,1
2014-09-25T06:46:03.249Z,13.05,14.19,0.48,0.02,1
2014-09-25T06:45:03.410Z,13.09,14.24,0.56,0.06,1
2014-09-25T06:44:02.677Z,13.07,14.24,0.52,0.03,1
2014-09-25T06:43:02.973Z,13.05,14.09,0.50,0.03,1
2014-09-25T06:42:03.282Z,13.09,14.24,0.52,0.03,1
2014-09-25T06:41:03.389Z,12.96,14.04,0.46,0.02,1
2014-09-25T06:40:02.702Z,12.76,13.59,0.50,0.00,1
```

I would like to add column 6 which is a boolean (0/1) value. In this sample data, the background would be fully highlighted as the bool is always true

Any tips?

Comment: It would be a good idea to include a sample of your data here and also reduce the script down to the bare minimum required for the question. When you say "highlight", what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `boxes` plotting style to draw background boxes depending on the value of column 6, i.e. something like

```
plot "sampleData.csv" using 1:($6 * 16) with boxes fc rgb '#ccffcc' fillstyle solid,\
     "" using 1:2 lt 1 with lines lw 2 title 'Batt (V)'
```

That, however, requires you to know the maximum and minimum values of the y-range. If that should be calculated automatically, you'll need first to make a dummy plot with the `unknown` terminal and then use `GPVAL_Y_MIN` and `GPVAL_Y_MAX`:

```
reset
set datafile separator ","
set terminal pngcairo size 800,400
set title "Solar charge monitor"
set yrange [0:]
set ylabel "V"
set y2range [0:]
set y2label "A"
set y2tics
set xlabel "Date"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
set key left center
set grid
set autoscale xfix
set style data lines

set terminal push
set terminal unknown
plot "sampleData.csv" using 1:2, "" using 1:3
set terminal pop

set output "samplePlot.png"
plot "sampleData.csv" using 1:(GPVAL_Y_MIN + $6 * (GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN)) with boxes fc rgb '#ccffcc' fillstyle solid notitle,\
     "" using 1:2 lt 1 lw 2 title 'Batt (V)', \
     "" using 1:3 lt 2 lw 2 title 'Solar (V)', \
     "" using 1:4 lt 3 lw 2 title 'Charge (A)' axes x1y2, \
     "" using 1:5 lt 4 lw 2 title 'Load (A)' axes x1y2
```

Using a slightly changed data file (I inserted some zeros to show the effect), I get:

[image]

If you don't want vertical lines at the boundaries, you could also use `filledcurves` with:

```
...
plot "sampleData.csv" using 1:(GPVAL_Y_MIN + $6 * (GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN)) with filledcurves x1 fc rgb '#ccffcc' fillstyle solid notitle,
...
```

[image]